# Can Spring Cloud Sleuth trace HTTP calls made through Async RestTemplate

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to trace HTTP calls made through [Async RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-async-resttemplate) from a Spring Boot Application.
I have a ZipKin instance running locally to which the microservices in question point to.

I could see spans recorded at every service in ZipKin UI, however I am not able to see the trace covering all the spans.

With [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) the trace is recorded as normal. i.e. I am able to see end-to-end via the UI.

Any pointers will help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work out of the box. An example is here - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/brewery/blob/8fc5bdbd6a65306bc3c4d088d20f5d14edbf3af2/brewing/src/main/java/io/spring/cloud/samples/brewery/bottling/BottlerService.java#L81 . Can you post your sample somewhere? Either there's a bug or you're doing sth wrong

Comment: Maybe try with the latest releases? Is it working fine with 1.0.12 or 1.1.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are expecting, you can add this dependancy in `pom.xml` if you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and a `AlwaysSampler @Bean` in your `SpringBootApplication` class

```
@Bean
public AlwaysSampler defaultSampler(){
    return new AlwaysSampler();
}
```

This will help you to sample your inputs in zipkin all time.